# Angular 5 and json formatting -> not well formatted

Tags: json, angular

I have an array with a json object

```
msgBodyDetailArr = [
    {
      Body: [
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Tomato Soup', Category: 'Groceries', Price: 1.0 },
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Yo-yo', Category: 'Toys', Price: 3.75 },
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Hammer', Category: 'Hardware', Price: 16.99 }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Now I would like to view this in my angular app, so I have created a very simple page:

```
<div class="list-group" *ngFor="let item of msgBodyDetailArr; let i=index">
  <div class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"> Message body </h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text"> {{item.Body | json }} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to work with the build in json pipe but the output of the view is like this:

Message body
[ { "Id": 1, "Name": "Tomato Soup", "Category": "Groceries", "Price": 1 }, { "Id": 2, "Name": "Yo-yo", "Category": "Toys", "Price": 3.75 }, { "Id": 3, "Name": "Hammer", "Category": "Hardware", "Price": 16.99 } ]

Is there a way to have it formatted like this?

```
{ Id: 1, Name: 'Tomato Soup', Category: 'Groceries', Price: 1.0 },
{ Id: 2, Name: 'Yo-yo', Category: 'Toys', Price: 3.75 },
{ Id: 3, Name: 'Hammer', Category: 'Hardware', Price: 16.99 }
```

Many thanks,
Lino

Comment: `JSON` pipe just reutrn your data into `json` format as per window size , if you need to beautify your data into DOM you should iterate over it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this solution

use `<pre>` tag

```
<div class="list-group" *ngFor="let item of msgBodyDetailArr; let i=index">
  <div class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"> Message body </h4>
    <pre class="list-group-item-text"> {{item.Body | json }} </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

> or

```
<div class="list-group" *ngFor="let item of msgBodyDetailArr">
  <div class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"> Message body </h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text" *ngFor="let singleObj of item.Body">{{singleObj | json }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

as it array you can try like this

```
  <p class="list-group-item-text" *ngFor="let member of item.Body">
     {{member | json }} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display objects of an array then you have to iterate `Body` array. To achieve this you have to use `*ngFor` one more time to iterate `Body` array.

```
<div class="list-group" *ngFor="let item of msgBodyDetailArr">
  <div class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"> Message body </h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text" *ngFor="let obj of item.Body">{{obj | json }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```